# how to disable tornado return 200 in an empty handler

Tags: tornado

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        pass
```

I found tornado will return 200 in this case
  How can I disable it.

Comment: `asynchonous` is redundant when `coroutine` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, Tornado will use 200 if response code is not explicitly set, or error occurred. It would be hard to find out that method is "empty" - only pass, without inspecting traceback, that is overkill IMHO.

So either you set status code in the method

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        self.set_status(501, 'Not implemented')
```

or remove entirely`post` method if it isn't used, client will receive **405 Method Not Allowed**.